# OsmAnd+ change text foreground or background color

Tags: osmand

I really like OsmAnd, but since the last update I can't see entries correctly, as the text foreground color and background color is white. I can see the text when I press and hold the item. This is very annoying. How can I change either the foreground or background color? Is this problem specific to my ROM (CyanogenMod 11) on my phone (Samsung GT-I9505), or is this a more generic issue? Thanks!

[image: OsmAnd display] [image: my phone]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: The map management has the same issue: map names and sources have white text on white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a problem in OsmAnd+ 2.3.5 but from the settings there appears that you can only choose between 'dark' and 'light' themes and there are no options for further customisation.

Your problem may also be to do with [this issue](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/1419) in which case the suggested solution is to go and explicitly select one of the themes in the settings.

[image: Light theme]
[image: Dark theme]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It's only working correctly in dark theme.